# How To Delete A value Automatically datetime php

Tags: php, sql, dynamic, timer

I want to display a message between two date in my web page when the finish time this message automatically deleted from page and database i dont want to use Trigger what can i use for this ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you might want to go with a cron job to do something like this. 

You will need to write a PHP script to access your database and perform scheduled clean up like this every 5, 10, 15 minutes whatever interval you choose.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/

Comment: Or you might be looking for a $_SESSION (http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.session.php).

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use JOB instead? Some SQL Server Agent, can do that for you.